# Confused with "Working of onBindViewHolder" in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am a beginner and I am working on an Android project. I am creating an announcement tab with the Fields Title, Description , Location of the Event, Time of Event. The Idea is Admin of the app will announce some announcements and all the app users will get the Announcements.

There are some situations where the fields Location and time of the event fields are empty. So, I have created two Cardviews to show the announcements. One with those fields and another without those two fields. So Whenever admin do not enter those two fields the Adapter should switch to second card view and should be displayed on the recycler view. But Recycler is showing only one view even though the Time and location fields are not present.

[Snapshot of CardView with All Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNOCJ.png)

[Snapshot of CardView without Location and Time fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r83Fr.png)

**OnBindViewHolder:**

Added a boolean Flag name **flagdatelocation** to know if those two fields are null or not. So, if those fields are null I made the flagdatelocation as false there by passsing it to **onCreateViewHolder** so as to decide on the selection of the cardview to opt. I have declared the flagdatelocation as global variable inside the class and inialised it with true.(not Static)

**NOTE:** If I do not initiate the flag as true, I am getting a Null Pointer Exception.

```
 boolean flagdateLocation=true;

 protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AnnounceHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Announcements model) {
     holder.textViewTitle.setText(model.getTitle());
     holder.textViewDesc.setText(model.getDescription());
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: "+model.getLocation()+" "+model.getDate());
     if (model.getDate()!=null&&model.getLocation()!=null){
         flagdateLocation = true;
         holder.textViewLocation.setText(model.getLocation());
         holder.textViewDate.setText(model.getDate());

     }
     else{
         flagdateLocation = false;
     }

    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: 2"+flagdateLocation);


    String creationDate="";
    Date date = model.getTimestamp();
    if (date != null) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL, Locale.US);
        creationDate = dateFormat.format(date);
        Log.d("TAG", creationDate);
    }
     holder.textViewTodayDate.setText(creationDate);

}
```

**OnCreateViewHolder:**

I have added if Condition to check for the flag that was declared in OnBindViewHolder depending on those fields being the null or not, so to opt for the desired the Cardview.

```
public AnnounceHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View V;
   if (flagdateLocation == false) {
       V = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.announcements_card_view_without_l_s, parent, false);
   }
   else{
       V = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.announcements_card_view, parent, false);
    }


    return new AnnounceHolder(V);
}
```

**Firebase Struture:**

[Cloud Firestore where the fields are updated depending on the Admin Announcing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvL3Q.png)

The Issue is even though the fields are null the Recyclerview is always showing the same Cardview. The if condition is somehow not working. My Question is that is my Approach for the requirement is correct or any other way is needed to be implemented. Where did I gone Wrong?

**Total RecylerAdapter:**

```
public class AnnouncementsAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Announcements, AnnouncementsAdapter.AnnounceHolder> {

boolean flagdateLocation;

public AnnouncementsAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Announcements> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AnnounceHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Announcements model) {
     holder.textViewTitle.setText(model.getTitle());
     holder.textViewDesc.setText(model.getDescription());
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: "+model.getLocation()+" "+model.getDate());
     if (model.getDate()!=null&&model.getLocation()!=null){
         flagdateLocation = true;
         holder.textViewLocation.setText(model.getLocation());
         holder.textViewDate.setText(model.getDate());

     }
     else{
         flagdateLocation = false;
     }

    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: 2"+flagdateLocation);


    String creationDate="";
    Date date = model.getTimestamp();
    if (date != null) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL, Locale.US);
        creationDate = dateFormat.format(date);
        Log.d("TAG", creationDate);
    }
     holder.textViewTodayDate.setText(creationDate);

}

@NonNull
@Override
public AnnounceHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View V;
   if (flagdateLocation == false) {
       V = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.announcements_card_view_without_l_s, parent, false);
   }
   else{
      V = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.announcements_card_view, parent, false);
    }

    V = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.announcements_card_view, parent, false);


    return new AnnounceHolder(V);
}


class AnnounceHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView textViewTitle;
    TextView textViewDesc;
    TextView textViewLocation;
    TextView textViewDate;
    TextView textViewTodayDate;
    public AnnounceHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_announcements);
        textViewDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description_announcements);
        textViewLocation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_announcemets);
        textViewDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_announcements);
        textViewTodayDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.todays_date);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please someone help me

Comment: you don't need two views for this. have one view with all the fields and before you send your arraylist of data to your RV to show it, filter it and remove the elements that you do not wanna show. This way, your recyclerView will work faster because there will be less code to run in the onBindViewHolder block.

Comment: How filter and remove the fields that are not needed? I am updating the data(fileds) to the firebase and then retrieving to show it in the recyclerview. Whenever those two fields are not present in the firebase data, Recycler shouldn't show.

Comment: when you receive the data from firebase, do you put it in an arraylist or viewModel?

Comment: After I remove those data also, I am getting the same cardview with location and time field showing empty. So even if I put them in arraylist and remove unwanted fields. The same problem occurs.

Comment: please share the whole RecyclerView adapter and not just the overridden methods. that would be more understandable

Comment: Added mehran, Could You Please Check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps:

```
public AnnounceHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View V;

    V = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.announcements_card_view, parent, false);

    return new AnnounceHolder(V);
}
```

And:

```
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AnnounceHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Announcements model) {
 holder.textViewTitle.setText(model.getTitle());
 holder.textViewDesc.setText(model.getDescription());
Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: "+model.getLocation()+" "+model.getDate());
 if (model.getDate()!=null&&model.getLocation()!=null){
     
     //SET THE VIEWS YOU WANNA SEE TO VISIBLE
     holder.YOUR_DATE_FILED.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     holder.YOUR_LOCATION_FILED.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

     holder.textViewLocation.setText(model.getLocation());
     holder.textViewDate.setText(model.getDate());

 }
 else{
     //SET THE VIEWS YOU DON'T WANNA SEE TO GONE
     holder.YOUR_DATE_FILED.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     holder.YOUR_LOCATION_FILED.setVisibility(View.GONE)
     
 }

Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: 2"+flagdateLocation);


String creationDate="";
Date date = model.getTimestamp();
if (date != null) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL, Locale.US);
    creationDate = dateFormat.format(date);
    Log.d("TAG", creationDate);
}
 holder.textViewTodayDate.setText(creationDate);

}
```

Comment: Thanks Mehran☺️. Will check and let you know.

Comment: Sure. I just added a few lines. you just need to copy and replace the code I gave you.

Comment: Sure Mehran. Thanks for the support.

Comment: I just downloaded the app you kept in  your profile. Excellent UI. Super sir!
My question is how much time it took for you to do it?

Comment: Thanks for your complement, man. It took a couple of months because I am working and I only spent my free time on this app.

Comment: Wow  Just two months for such an amazing UI and code. You are terrific. Where did you learn the Android development sir? Sources?

Comment: not two months. by a couple of months I mean a few months. If I wanna be more accurate I have to say about 8 months. no specific sources. I do a lot of research, read articles and watch YouTube videos but https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMvagHKkUlt3t_E4KxwQXXQ , https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_Fh8kvtkVPkeihBs42jGcA and https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0FPjuZLQ16UpvLtbs6LYpg are really good channels for learning. check them out.

Comment: Oh..Thanks Mehran. Subscribed. People like you are inspiration to the beginners like me

Comment: Thanks you so much Mehran the code worked. I could see that view got eliminated. I can not upvote your code as I have no reputation points

Comment: It's alright bro no worries. I'm glad I could help. thanks a lot for all the complements. Happy coding

Comment: Thanks Mehran. Happy coding. ☺️